# update_order_review( ) on button click

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a custom button on my checkout page, on click I'm adding a product to cart via AJAX.

JS:

```
$('#add_domain_product').on('click', function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: Ajax.ajaxurl,
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                action: 'add_domain_product',
            },
            success: function (data, status, xhr) {
                // update command is executed.
                console.log(data);
            }

        });
    })
```

PHP:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_add_domain_product', 'bs_add_domain_product');
function bs_add_domain_product() {
    global $woocommerce;
    $woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart('633');
    exit();
}
```

After that, I'd need to refresh the order review, so it displays my newly added product also. How can I do that?

Comment: I was just about to ask a very similar question. Did you solve this? In theory, you should be able to do this by using something like `WC_AJAX::update_order_review();` in your `bs_add_domain_product()` function. That *should* return the fragments for updating the checkout; however it's currently returning a fairly useless `-1` for me, which means there's potentially an error somewhere in WooCommerce's handing of that particular function. Or else I'm completely misunderstanding it.

Comment: See the accepted solution, works like a charm.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

All you need to do is call a trigger on the body to update the cart.

```
$( 'body' ).trigger( 'update_checkout' );
```

This will automatically call all the subsequent AJAX calls needed to refresh the cart information, including the order review.

Answer (score 11):

In Checkout page:

```
jQuery(document.body).trigger("update_checkout")
```

In Cart page:

```
jQuery(document.body).trigger("wc_update_cart");
```