# Hook in cart update on change

Tags: ajax, wordpress, woocommerce, product-quantity

I have a Woocommerce One Page Checkout and I have the quantity input changed to a select box according [this](https://www.vanpattenmedia.com/2014/code-snippet-woocommerce-quantity-select-field) snippet.

Now I want that when I change my quantity with the select, the quantity in my shopping cart also updates with the selected quantity using AJAX. How can I achieve this in my functions.php?

The [snippet](https://gist.github.com/rours/637b722debac38037766) later on that page does not what it should do. Can someone help me out?

Update:

Could [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27635186/update-order-review-on-button-click) maybe part of my solution?